# Переменная в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть регулярка, в которой нужно использовать переменную, например, чтоб было в виде:

```
replace(/<[\s+]?тут должна быть переменная[\s+]?([^<]*)?>/gim, '<переменная $1 />');
```

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var re = new RegExp('<[\s+]?' + variable + '[\s+]?([^<]*)?>', 'gim');`

Answer (score 3):

**Ответ**:

```
new RegExp('<[\\s+]?' + variable.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&') + '[\\s+]?([^<]*)>','gi')
```

Если есть поддержка ES6:

```
new RegExp(`<[\\s+]?${variable.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&')}[\\s+]?([^<]*)>`, 'gi')
new RegExp(String.raw`<[\s+]?${variable.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&')}[\s+]?([^<]*)>`, 'gi')
```

**Подробности**

- **Конкатенация строк**. Чтобы вставить переменную в выражение, нужно объединить два и более строковых литералов. Чаще всего для этого используется оператор `+`, но в ES6 появились "шаблонные" строковые литералы (*template string literals*), поддерживающие строковую интерполяцию.
- **Обратная косая черта**. Так как в строковых литералах символ обратной косой черты используется для формирования строковых escape-последовательностей (`\t` — знак табуляции, `\n` — символ переноса на новую строку), чтобы написать один буквальный символ `\` нужно его удвоить: `"a\\b"` или `` `a\\b` `` — это строка `a\b`, тогда как `"a\b"` или `` `a\b` `` — это строка `ab`. А вот в "сыром" строковом литерале можно смело использовать 1 знак обратной косой черты: `` String.raw`a\b` `` — это строка `a\b`.
- **Экранирование**. Так как в переменной `variable` чаще всего содержится буквальный текст, не шаблон, все символы, являющиеся специальными метасимволами регулярных выражений, должны быть экранированы с помощью `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&')`. Если в строке могут быть только буквы или цифры, экранирование не требуется.

Пример ES5:

```js
var variable = "[()]";
console.log(new RegExp('<[\\s+]?' + variable.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&') + '[\\s+]?([^<]*)>','gi'));
```

ES6+:

```js
var variable = "[()]";
console.log(new RegExp(`<[\\s+]?${variable.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&')}[\\s+]?([^<]*)>`, 'gi'));
console.log(new RegExp(String.raw`<[\s+]?${variable.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&')}[\s+]?([^<]*)>`, 'gi'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите тут. Переменную можно организовтаь через скобки и вызвать по $1-$9.

> Находит x и запоминает. Это называется "запоминающие скобки". Например, /(foo)/ найдет и запомнит 'foo' в "foo bar." Найденная подстрока хранится в массиве-результате поиска или в предопределенных свойствах объекта RegExp: $1, ..., $9. Кроме того, скобки объединяют то, что в них находится, в единый элемент паттерна. Например, (abc)* - повторение abc 0 и более раз.

Вообще вот полезная статья про [регулярки](http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression).