# Как динамически с помощью переменных и регулярного выражения поменять последнее значение в строке?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно динамически с помощью переменных и регулярного выражения поменять последнее значение в строке.
В первом случае работает во втором нет.
За ответ спасибо заранее.

```js
var str01 = "200_String_200_String";
var str02 = "200_String_200_String_20_String";
var mx = '200';
var dx = '400';
var str1 = str01.replace(new RegExp('200([^200]*)$', ''), dx + '$1');
var str2 = str02.replace(new RegExp('' + mx + '([^' + mx + ']*)$', ''), dx + '$1');

document.getElementById('ok1').innerHTML = str1;
document.getElementById('ok2').innerHTML = str2;
```

```html
<div id="ok1"></div>
<div id="ok2"></div>
```

Comment: второе не работает, так как у тебя получается другая строка, не `'200([^200]*)$'` а `'400([^400]*)$'` - так как у тебя переменная dx = '400'

Comment: Но первое выражение тоже неправильное, просто повезло, что на данное строке сработало.

Comment: Я задал вопрос не для критики и тестирования, я просто ищу ответа. Если первый вариант работает, то он не может быть не правильным. Сам понимаю что второй вариант не работает. Но вместо того что бы получить нормальный и адекватный ответ, вопрос пометили как дубликат, и подтвердили что второй вариант не работает...

Comment: Этот ответ я видел Переменная в регулярном выражении - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82765/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8. Но так как и вы, я не увидел там ответа на мой вопрос, для моего примера. Поэтому и задал свой вопрос.

Comment: @МаксимБелов, так вам ответили в комментарии, у вас ищется 400~400 в строчке где такого нет. Более того, даже если было-бы, то заменяется на то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек за понятный ответ, исправил и все заработало. Ответить то ответили, выражение написал неправильное и дубликатный вопрос, заминусовали, набросились с негативом. Это меня и запутало...

Comment: @МаксимБелов, но выражение все равно неверно, потому что в квадратных скобках указывается группа символов, то есть `[^200]` - эквивалентно `[^20]`, `[^02]`.

Comment: @Grundy. "Спасибо  за обозначение вопроса как дубликат и за определение того что выражение в другом случае не работает". Но я ищу здесь ответа, а не критики и минусы.

Comment: @МаксимБелов, после редактирования, вопрос перестал быть дубликатом.

Answer (score 2):

Одним из возможных решений является  "жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор (англ. "tempered greedy token") `(?:(?!<переменная>).)*`:

```js
var str01 = "200_String_200_String";
var str02 = "200_String_200_String_20_String";
var mx = '200';
var dx = '400';
var str1 = str01.replace(new RegExp('200((?:(?!200).)*)$', ''), dx + '$1');
var str2 = str02.replace(new RegExp('' + mx + '((?:(?!' + mx.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ').)*)$', ''), dx + '$1');

document.getElementById('ok1').innerHTML = str1;
document.getElementById('ok2').innerHTML = str2;
```

```html
<div id="ok1"></div>
<div id="ok2"></div>
```

На всякий случай, я добавил `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')`, если в переменной `mx` окажутся символы, являющиеся специальными метасимволами регулярных выражений, которые находят сами себя только если они экранированы.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/0wPJ3w/1).

Если в строке могут быть знаки перевода на новую строку, замените `(?:(?!<переменная>).)*` на `(?:(?!<переменная>)[^])*`.