# Поиск и замена строки в квдратных скобках с использованием конструктора RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения, replace

```
var html = '<input name="setting[my_tab][1]"/><input name="setting[my_tab][2]"/>';
var tab_code = 'my_tab';

var pattern = 'setting[' + tab_code  + ']';
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
html.replace(regex, 'setting[other]');

console.log(html);
```

Ничего не меняет, надо что бы было

```
<input name="setting[other][1]"/><input name="setting[other][2]"/>
```

Comment: `var pattern = 'setting\\[' + tab_code  + ']'; html = html.replace(regex, 'setting[other]');`

Comment: Да, заработало, спасибо большое, правда не мог найти документацию, где описывалось бы про слеши

Comment: Посмотрите https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-escaping

Comment: См. [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/997416/182013), можно использовать универсальный подход: `var regex = new RegExp(pattern.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,'\\$&'), 'g');`